# Display Image alt text using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to display the alt text for an image as a paragraph with a class using **vanilla JavaScript**.

**Example:**

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="These are planets">
```

**Rendered As:**

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="These are planets">
<p class="photo-caption">These are planets</p>
```

Comment: Why would you do this using Javascript? It seems to make a lot more sense to just write the `<p>`? Why would the alt txt change? Also if you search read `alt text javascript` I'm sure you'd get lots of questions giving you what you need

Comment: Adding one thing to it - I'd like to only add the caption if the image has a class. Something like "If image has class"add-caption, then display the paragraph".

Comment: Because I'm using Jekyll and displaying the images via markdown - trying to eliminate adding multiple elements and html manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. Note that it uses es6 functions

```js
const images = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('img') );

images.forEach(image => {
  let alt = image.getAttribute('alt');
  
  if( alt )
  {
    image.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', `<p class="caption">${alt}</p>`); 
  }
});
```

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/240/280/any" alt="These are planets">
<img src="https://placeimg.com/240/280/any" alt="These are something">
<img src="https://placeimg.com/240/280/any" alt="Something else">
<img src="https://placeimg.com/240/280/any" alt="Something">
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it's useful to anyone here's what I ended up with and it worked perfectly. This is useful if you'd like to selectively add captions to images without adding additional HTML to your Markdown:

**Jekyll/Github pages markdown:**

```
![These are planets](path/to/image.jpg){: .add-caption}
```

**On build it will render:**

```
<img class="add-caption" src="image.jpg" alt="These are planets">
```

**Using @SuperDJ's JS**

```
  const images = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('.add-caption') );
  images.forEach(image => {
    let alt = image.getAttribute('alt');
    if( alt )
    {image.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', `<p class="photo-caption">${alt}</p>`);}
  });
```

**Final Output HTML:**

```
<img class="add-caption" src="image.jpg" alt="These are planets">
<p class="photo-caption">These are planets</p>
```

**Add CSS:**

```
.photo-caption {
  color: #999;
  font-size: .5rem;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Hope it's helpful to you. I searched the web for an hour and couldn't find a solution.